What happens if I reduce to half its size the swap partition?
I have a 32GB swap partition in Ubuntu, if I go to Windows and free that partition and after I reduce that partition to 16GB what happens if I restart Ubuntu? I don't know if it won't let me access Ubuntu or if I will be able to access it and then give one 16GB partition to swap. I need that to expand the filesystem root.


better question: why are you using a swappartition? we stopped doing that a long long time ago. Oh and please follow the corect method: "swap off" in Ubuntu command line ALL methods outside of Ubuntu can break the system.

Those with servers suggest a 4GB swap partition just to have some. But default desktop install uses a 2GB swap file. Only if hibernating, do you need swap slightly more than RAM, but hibernation not recommended.

Your /etc/fstab swap mount probably uses the UUID, so that needs an edit for the new one.  Shouldn't prevent your boot to do the edit though.

The effect will vary with details you've not provided, esp. your product (Server? Desktop?) and what apps you use, and how you use those apps & your system. I've used systems where reducing swap (partition/file) size reduced speed rather noticeably  (no system crashes; system just became somewhat laggy) yet on other systems that did other roles I could remove swap entirely.  Look at your product, apps & usage of the system (details you didn't provide) in order to determine effect.
